# Bad Grammar Error In Named Query Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

When I try to run this query with hibernate in Java somethings go wrong and throws an error like

```
( 12002 ) Internal Service Error. Exception Message : Bad Sql Grammar Exception occurred [Hibernate operation: could not execute query; bad SQL grammar [SELECT COMDT_COM_STAT, COMDT_COM_REFNO, COMDT_COM_CCY  
            FROM COMDT 
            WHERE COMDT_COM_REFNO = ? 
            AND COMDT_COM_RDN BETWEEN ? AND ? 
            AND COMDT_COM_STAT = ?
            GROUP BY COMDT_COM_STAT, COMDT_COM_REFNO, COMDT_COM_CCY 
            ORDER BY COMDT_COM_REFNO]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Column Name]
```

But when I run the same query with proper inputs in PLSQL, everything works as I expected. I am working on this error for 2 days but nothing came up.

Thanks.

## QUERY

```
<sql-query name="getCommissionBetweenDatesWithStat">
        <return alias="xyz"
            class="com.ykb.hmn.cms.commission.datamodel.IComDetail"/>
        <![CDATA[ 
        SELECT COMDT_COM_CCY AS {xyz.currency}, SUM(xyz.COMDT_COM_AMT1) AS {xyz.amount1} 
        FROM COMDT 
        WHERE COMDT_COM_REFNO = :refNo 
        AND COMDT_COM_RDN BETWEEN :startRdn AND :endRdn 
        AND COMDT_COM_STAT = :stat
        GROUP BY COMDT_COM_STAT, COMDT_COM_REFNO, COMDT_COM_CCY 
        ORDER BY COMDT_COM_REFNO
        ]]>
</sql-query>
```

## Entity

```
<class name="com.ykb.hmn.cms.commission.datamodel.IComDetail"
        table="COMDT">
        <tuplizer class="com.ykb.hmn.inf.core.datamodel.IntfEntityTuplizer"
            entity-mode="pojo" />
        <id name="oid" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column length="17" name="COMDT_ID" />
        </id>
        <property name="refNo" type="long">
            <column length="12" name="COMDT_COM_REFNO" />
        </property>
        <property name="stat" type="string">
            <column length="1" name="COMDT_COM_STAT" />
        </property>
        <property name="relDay" type="int">
            <column length="5" name="COMDT_COM_RDN" />
        </property>
        <property name="amount1" type="big_decimal">
            <column precision="18" scale="2" name="COMDT_COM_AMT1" />
        </property>
        <property name="currency" type="string">
            <column length="4" name="COMDT_COM_CCY" />
        </property>

<class/>
```

## Table Schema

```
COMDT_ID NUMBER(17)
COMDT_COM_REFNO NUMBER(12)
COMDT_COM_AMT1 NUMBER(18,2)
COMDT_COM_STAT VARCHAR2(1)
COMDT_COM_RDN NUMBER(5)
COMDT_COM_CCY VARCHAR2(4)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you also post table schema?

Comment: Alright wait a bit

Comment: A few things pop up in my mind here: Why `XML` and not annotations?  Why using a native SQL query and not a proper HQL query or even a Criteria?

Comment: Agree with @Abhishek, try rewriting query with properties as defined in XML.

Comment: @StefanHaberl because im working on dinasaur project. It is being developed since 2008 and i am trying to implement new function in it

Comment: Did you try executing the query with an SQL client? which DB are you using? Would be interesting to see, which column is invalid

Comment: Yes i said it above :)

Answer (score 0):

My guess, hibernate named query should be declared using the property name, not the column name. So instead of using column name in the named query, use the property name.

See this example for more details:
https://www.journaldev.com/3451/hibernate-named-query-example-namedquery